# Getting a unexpected output

Tags: javascript, maps

```
function normalize() {
   console.log(this.coords.map(function(x){
      return x/this.length;
 }));
}

normalize.call({coords: [0, 2, 3], length: 5});
```

Expected output: [0,0.4,0.6]

Output:[NaN, Infinity, Infinity]

Can someone explain the error?

Comment: do you really need to use `call`?

Comment: By using 'this' and not binding it to the map function as well, this.length will refer to the length of the mapping function, so 0 instead of to the object you used call on. So in reality you calculate 0 / 0, 2 / 0 and 3 / 0 which produce your output. Nina posted the fix for this. It would be preferred imho though, to use a parameter instead of the this keyword.

Comment: @NinaScholz I am new to Javascript...just exploring its features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take `this` along with the function for mapping with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). Without `thisArg`, the callback has no access to `this`.

```js
function normalize() {
    return this.coords.map(function (x) {
        return x/this.length;
    }, this);
}

console.log(normalize.call({ coords: [0, 2, 3], length: 5 }));
```

Comment: If we had used an arrow function to divide by length we don't specify 'this' right?